# How to get Annotation from TFS using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, tfs, annotations

This document describes how to get the Annotation of a file from TFS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979.aspx

I am interested in obtaining the Annotation of a file using PowerShell. Any ideas if this is possible and if so, how one would go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can run normal MSDOS commands in PowerShell, I'd recomment installing the Team Foundation PowerTools from:

For 2008:

- http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBD14EEA-781F-45A1-8C46-9F6BA2F68BF0&displaylang=en

For 2010:

- http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f

Using "tfpt annotate" and parsing the output.

Grant Holiday talks about automating the process here is you want to pass the whuffie on:

- [TFS annotate/blame summary report for a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74526/tfs-annotate-blame-summary-report-for-a-project)

Answer (score 0):

[PsTFS from Codeplex](http://pstfs.codeplex.com/) is a set of PowerShell commands to manage and use Team Foundation Server. May it help I don't test it.