# Code Metrics per TFS User

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, code-metrics

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2010 or TFS 2010 to calculate the Code Metrics of a Solution but have it split per TFS user?

For example:

User A: 250,000 Lines

User B: 23,000 Lines

User C: 12,000 Lines

ect.

Comment: Lines *what*? Lines edited, added, deleted? What would you expect this metric to actually show (or actually *mean*)?

Comment: The number of lines attributed to each TFS user, whether edited or added. If you 'annotate' a file in TFS (through VS) it tells you which User is attributed to each line. I'd like to find a way to show the number of lines of code attributed to each TFS User in a solution if it's at all possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74526/tfs-annotate-blame-summary-report-for-a-project